# What are panths (पंथ)?

Tags: culture, tradition, customs

I'm from a place in India where some groups like panths have existed for a long time. Since we are in a modern age they aren't seen or heard about much but still as the older people do coexist so does the panth too.

My grandfather had died recently and we have to invite some people who held some special ceremony for this too (my grandfather was a member of a panth).

There are many things related to that ceremony which aren't disclosed to others but only panth members. Also there's a custom which demands that one family member of the deceased should join the panth. There are also people called *Nath*.

Any clarifications and/or additional information is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.